# Python Flask waitress-serve command-line call argument?

Tags: python, flask, waitress

I have the following simple py file below. It works fine if I type `python damn.py`, but it says not to use it as production server. I have installed waitress. In my case, what exactly should the argument in the " " be? I have tried `waitress-serve --call "damn:create_app"`, but it id not work.

damn.py

```
from flask import Flask

api = Flask(__name__)

@api.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
  return "Hello world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
waitress-serve --help
```

lists the following on the `--call` flag:

> Call the given object to get the WSGI application.

You have no `create_app` function that returns the WSGI application. You don't need the call flag since you're not using the [`Application Factory pattern`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/).

You can just do:

```
waitress-serve "damn:api"
```